# Является ли Go ...?

Tags: golang, gui

- Является ли язык Go кроссплатформенным?
- И есть ли какие нибудь гибкие средства программирования GUI под windows на Go? (желательно поподробнее). Есть ли паттерны проектирования наподобие MVVM?

Comment: GUI на go не лучшая идея

Comment: @Sublihim а как делают интерактивные сервисы на Go?

Comment: Или Go служит только для серверной части проекта?

Comment: А клиенты делаются на том чём удобнее

Comment: go, да в основном для серверной части.

Comment: @Sublihim ладно оформите красиво ответом

Comment: вот https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#gui

Comment: @biosckon , топ, то что надо, спасибо

Comment: Можно писать очень большие сервисы и 100000 горутин (параллельные потоки) легковесны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go скорее правильно назвать кроскомпилируемым языком
- Скорость выполнения, небольшое потребление памяти, простое
  распаралелливание позволяет писать небольшие web-сервисы, серверную
  часть приложений (бэкэнды), парсеры, краулеры, девопс и
  административные утилиты.   Есть библиотеки позволяющие писать GUI
  приложения на golange, но все-таки GUI - это не лучшая область
  применения этого языка, по моему мнению.

Answer (score 1):

Да Go является кросс платформенным языком.

Для переключения между системами используются переменные среды, при этом в коде ничего менять не нужно.

Например, для Unix платформ необходимы установить переменные среды:

```
SET GOOS=linux
SET GOARCH=amd64
SET CGO_ENABLED=0
```

Для Go подойдет и самый простой редактор. Но есть предпочтения у каждого свои.

Вот список:

- Goland IDE (старое название - Gogland)
- Visual Studio Code + go plugin
- LiteIDE
- Wide
- Atom + go-plus plugin
- Eclipse + GoClipse
- Sublime Text + GoSublime
- Vim + vim-go plugin

**GUI**

Да есть библиотеки :

- [**ui**](https://github.com/andlabs/ui) - простой но малофункциональный
- [**sciter**](https://github.com/sciter-sdk/go-sciter) - лучше чем первый но сложный и трудоемкий
- [**qt**](https://github.com/therecipe/qt) - среднее между первым и вторым

Писать очень сложно и долго.

Comment: лучше выделенные слова в ссылки превратить. Я, к примеру, смутно представляю, где искать *ui* библиотеку (и библиотека это?)

Comment: @KoVadim, добавил ссылки

Comment: Спасибо коллеги.